# issue while taking photo wtth flash On using AVCapturePhotoOutput

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, avcapturephotosettings

I am working on camera app. i am using AVCapturePhotoOutput for ios 10.x device and AVCaptureStillImageOutput for below 10.x devices.

I am using below capture settings while capturing Photo

```
let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()

let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
        let previewFormat = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
                             kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 1080,
                             kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 1080,
                             ]
settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat
settings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = true
settings.flashMode = .on
settings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = true
self.captureOutputPhoto?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
```

when i am try to capture photo using above setting

```
captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer:previewPhotoSampleBuffer:resolvedSettings:bracketSettings:error
```

above delegate throws error first time. I am beginner for AVCapturePhotoSettings. the problem is occurs after every successful photo capture with flash mode.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the error message you are getting?

Comment: I am getting same error. error code -16005 error descritption : operation could not completed. this error comes after every successful image capture when flashmode set On

Comment: @Dhaval did you want to use another class for capture image with flash ?

Comment: i am used AVCapturePhotoOutput for iOS 10.x and AVCaptureStillImageOutput. AVCaptureStillImageOutput working properly for below 10.x devices. problem comes with AVCapturePhotoOutput in ios 10.x devices. AVCaptureStillImageOutput now deprecated.

Comment: below error comes while capture with flash after that preview layer stop rendering ::
(Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 \"The operation could not be completed\" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x174652060 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-16800 \"(null)\"}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-16800), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed})

Answer (score -1):

From [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotosettings/1648760-flashmode):

> You may not enable image stabilization if the flash mode is 
>   on
>   . (Enabling the flash takes priority over the 
>   isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled
>    setting.)

Not sure, if it should throw error, but you can try to remove this string

```
settings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = true
```

Comment: Checked by commenting `settings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = true` this line. still facing the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

[`captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer:previewPhotoSampleBuffer:resolvedSettings:bracketSettings:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotocapturedelegate/1778647-captureoutput), an Objective-C delegate method, whose Swift version is [`photoOutput(_:didFinishProcessingPhoto:previewPhoto:resolvedSettings:bracketSettings:error:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotocapturedelegate/1778647-photooutput), is deprecated.

Instead implement the Swift method [`photoOutput(_:didFinishProcessingPhoto:error:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturephotocapturedelegate/2873949-photooutput).

Answer (score -1):

I'm using this method for handling the flash settings. `AVCaptureDevice` is basically the camera that you are using and the `AVCaptureFlashMode` is the flash mode you want to use.

```
func changeFlashSettings(device: AVCaptureDevice, mode: AVCaptureFlashMode) {
    do {
        try device.lockForConfiguration()
        device.flashMode = mode
        device.unlockForConfiguration()
    } catch {
        print("Change Flash Configuration Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

With this you can set the flash setting to `on`, `off` or `auto`. Hope this helps.

Comment: this solution is working for perior than ios 10.x now AVCaptureStillImageOutput is deprecated

Comment: Even though AVCaptureStillImageOutput is deprecated this method still can be used for iOS 10.x versions. Before posting the answer I have tested the code on a real device that has the iOS version of 10.3.2.